# php modulus in a loop by displaying only 5 items per row

Tags: php, loops, modulus

I want to loop extra deetails.. by calculate the total items divided five. For example, i have 2 items, then i will add extra 3 div to it. When i have 8 items, i will add extra 2 div to it.

```
$totalcount = 2;
$check = $totalcount %5;
$totalcount = 8;
$check = $totalcount %5;
```

I found out i cant use this method because it loops wrongly. 
i will use extra loop to show the result when detect the main loop when reached end of loop.

```
if($key == $len - 1)
    for ($i = 0; $i < $check; $i++) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is there any solution, i can ensure `$totalcount%5` is always equal to zero and add extra div details to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do little bit of calculation to find out extra number of *divs* required. Given the fact that `$totalcount` is your number of rows, `$totalcount` would be your necessary number of *divs*. And subsequently you would have to calculate extra number of *divs* in the following way,

```
$totalcount = 7; // or some other value
$totaldivs = $totalcount + (5 - ($totalcount % 5));
$extradivs = $totaldivs - $totalcount; // extra divs
```

Finally you can use two loops, one printing actaul rows inside *divs* and other printing extra *divs*, like this:

```
// loop printing rows inside divs
for($i = 0; $ < $totalcount; ++$i){
    echo '<div>';
    // your rows
    echo '</div>';
}

// loop printing extra divs
for($i = 0; $ < $extradivs; ++$i){
    echo '<div>';
    ...
    echo '</div>';
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** I kept `if($key == $len - 1){ ... }` block outside of the equation but you can place it in the appropriate place as per your requirement.